# tomcat not detecting my classes

Tags: jsp, tomcat, tomcat7

I have made a class as below

```
:~/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/myclasses$ ls
myLog.class  myLog.java
:~/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/myclasses$ cat myLog.java
import java.io.*;

public class myLog
{
    private static PrintWriter log = null;
    public myLog(String logpath) throws IOException
    {
        log = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(logpath, true));
        log.println("Logging started\n");
    }
    p
```

I am tryinto access the same from my jsp as below,

```
<%@ page language = "java" %>
<%@ page import = "myclasses.*" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%
    myLog log = (myLog)application.getAttribute("logfile");
    try
    {
      if (log == null)
      {
        log = new myLog("new.log");
```

I am facing a class now found exception. I have restarted tomcat.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myLog

Can someone tell me why, please..

Comment: Is the .class file present in your WEB-INF/classes dir?

Comment: And it's just a style thing; but class names in Java are normally CamelCase.

Comment: yes. Just as I had shown above
:~/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/myclasses$ ls
myLog.class  myLog.java
:~/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/myclasses$ cat myLog.java
import java.io.*;

Comment: The first line of myLog.java should be package myclasses;

Comment: tried that too. Restarted.
created jar myclasses.jar with myLog.java in it..
restarted tomcat. Still same :-(

Comment: @rickz infact I had done it before you said and the error changed to java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError from java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myLog, but I never noticed it :-(
The version error was since I was compiling the class with javac version 1.7 and Apache was pointing to 1.6. Once this was corrected, I am able to see the page without errors.. Thank you all